# SQL Server 2008 - complex Insert Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, insert, dml

I`m not a SQL programmer, but I have encountered an obstacle during my project and have to construct a trigger, which will fire after insert command. The problem is as follows:

I have 3 tables:

```
dbo. Build

id   (PK, int, not null)
date (smalldatetime, not null)


dbo.TestCase

id   (PK, int, not null)
Name (nvarchar(200), not null)


dbo.TestCaseExecution

id              (PK, int, not null)
build_id        (FK, int, not null)
testcase_id     (FK, int, not null)
passed          (int, null)            //1 or 0
executed        (int, null)            //1 or 0
duration        (real, null)
fail_percentage (real, null)           //null
```

now, I read data from .xml files and add the data to database via project written in C#. After each build I have to update the database and count fail_percentage for each test basing  on 'passed' and 'executed' values.

```
fail_percentage = (100)*(1 - (PassNumber/ExecutionNumber))
```

so I need a trigger, which will:
1. fire after insert command
2. count fail_percentage basing on earlier values e.g.

```
after reading from file:

id  build_id  testcase_id  passed  executed  duration  fail_percentage
1   1         001          1       1         12:09     null

after trigger:

id  build_id  testcase_id  passed  executed  duration  fail_percentage
1   1         001          1       1         12:09     0

after reading from file:
id  build_id  testcase_id  passed  executed  duration  fail_percentage
1   1         001          1       1         12:09     0
2   2         001          0       1         12:32     null

after trigger:
id  build_id  testcase_id  passed  executed  duration  fail_percentage
1   1         001          1       1         12:09     0
2   2         001          0       1         12:32     50
```

could anyone give me a hand ?

Thanks in advance,
Artur

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  It looks to me like you don't need a trigger at all.  Why can't you just define fail_percentage as a computed column?

Comment: Tom H. yes, but I haven`t refused any... what I did wrong ?

Comment: EBarr - I was trying to do that, but there is a problem with passing the sum of values in 'passed' columns, it passes only actual value and I need the whole data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok

I did it without using triggers, inside my application I store all the needed data in a dictionary:

- test name as a key value
- pass value and executed value as a values

then I count percentage and insert it to the database.